# why is uploadify (jQuery Plugin) not working ? what is wrong with my code?

Tags: jquery, file-upload, uploadify

i had used this plugin before, but now when i want to use it for another project it simply does not work, where am i going wrong.

here is the code i am using in my root index.php file

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="/uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
      'uploader'  : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
      'script'    : '/uploadify/uploadify.php',
      'cancelImg' : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
      'folder'    : '/uploads',
      'auto'      : true
    });
    });
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />
</body>
</html>
```

and as per the instruction i have put the following file in the uploadify folder in root directory here is the screenshot of theuploadify directory.

[image]

where am i going wrong?

in case you want to check the documentation of the plugin here is the path.

http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/

Comment: Does the folder /uploads exist?

Comment: the regular html file upload button should be replaced by the uploadify button, that is not being replaced.

Comment: Do the js and css files all manage to load correctly?

Comment: The SWF file too? There are no Javascript error messages?

Comment: @Pekka the problem is the forward slash before the path.. it is solved. :) i removed all forwards slashes and it works now.

Comment: @Ibrahim always make sure whether the files you include actually load correctly, e.g. using the "resources" tab in Firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was the forward slash before the path.